# Filtering ObservableCollection items on UI

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF of tasks each has status of completed or pending, I will view all of these items into a list box, the tasks are serialized into XML file and these items are linked to UI through ObersvableCollection.

What I'm looking for it so be able to filter the tasks on the view and be able to edit or create new taks and save into the XML file.

I was thinking about creating a new class called `FilterTask.cs` and have static method `Completed()` which return ObersvableCollection item but I am not sure if this will affect the serialization process.

here is my code

```
main window XAML

<Window x:Class="UIToDoList_2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UIToDoList_2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="To Do List" Height="290" Width="500" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <StackPanel Name="MainPanel">
            <StackPanel Name="ViewTaskPanel" Margin="10">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Task" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ListBox x:Name="UITasks"  Width="300" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,10,5"
                                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="ShowAll" Content="Show All"/>
                        <RadioButton x:Name="ShowCompleted" Content="Show Completed" />
                        <RadioButton x:Name="ShowPending" Content="Show Pending"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel>
                        <Button Content="Mark As Completed" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Button Content="Mark As Pending" Margin="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Button x:Name="DltTaskBtn" Content="Delete Task"
                                Margin="0,0,0,5" Click="DltTaskBtn_Click"/>
                        <Button x:Name="RenameBtn" Content="Rename" Click="RenameBtn_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Name="AddTaskPanel" Margin="10">
                <TextBlock Text="Add New Task"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Task Name" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                    <TextBox Name="TaskNameTxt" Width="260"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button x:Name="AddTaskBtn" Content="Add" Margin="5" Click="AddTaskBtn_Click"/>
                    <Button x:Name="ClearTaskTxt" Content="Clear" Margin="5" Click="ClearTaskTxt_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Task.cs

```
public class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return this._Name; }
            set
            {
                if (this._Name != value)
                {
                    this._Name = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private Status _Status;

        public Status Status
        {
            get { return this._Status; }
            set
            {
                if (this._Status != value)
                {
                    this._Status = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
    }

    public enum Status
    {
        Pending = 0,
        Completed = 1
    }
```

TaskSerialization.cs

```
    public class TaskSerialization
    {
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public TaskSerialization(string fileName)
        {
            FileName = fileName;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize the task list to XML File
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tasks"></param>
        public void SerializeTasks(List<Task> tasks)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(FileName);
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Task>));
            sr.Serialize(sw, tasks);
            sw.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize the taks list form XML file and return as ObservableCollection item
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ObservableCollection<Task> DeserializeTasks()
        {
            XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Task>));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open);
            return new ObservableCollection<Task>((List<Task>)sr.Deserialize(fs));
        }
    }
```

Mainwindow.cs

```
namespace UIToDoList_2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly string fileName = "ToDoList.xml";
        private readonly TaskSerialization taskSrlz;
        ObservableCollection<Task> tasks = new ObservableCollection<Task>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            taskSrlz = new TaskSerialization(fileName);
            tasks = taskSrlz.DeserializeTasks();
            UITasks.ItemsSource = tasks;
        }

        private void AddTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AddTask();
        }
        private void DltTaskBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteTask();
        }

        private void AddTask()
        {
            var taskName = TaskNameTxt.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(taskName))
            {
                tasks.Add(new Task() { Name = TaskNameTxt.Text, Status = Status.Pending });
                taskSrlz.SerializeTasks(new List<Task>(tasks));
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Task name cannot be null", "Error in Task name", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

        }

        private void DeleteTask()
        {
            if(UITasks.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                var selectedTask = (UITasks.SelectedItem as Task);
                tasks.Remove(selectedTask);
                taskSrlz.SerializeTasks(new List<Task>(tasks));
            }
        }

        private void RenameBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UITasks.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                (UITasks.SelectedItem as Task).Name = TaskNameTxt.Text;
                taskSrlz.SerializeTasks(new List<Task>(tasks));
            }
        }

        private void ClearTaskTxt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TaskNameTxt.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [Binding to Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#binding-to-collections). There are sections about sorting and filtering.

Comment: Rather than using code behind, consider using the MVVM style of writing WPF applications.

Comment: @Clemens So do I need to create a CollectionViewSource and bind it to my listbox through XAML ? and I no longer need to use ObservableCollection?

Comment: @KevinCook can you explain more please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will mark this as answer based on clemens comment to look into binding into collections `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview#binding-to-collections`